# how to build release version mac cocos2dx?

Tags: cocos2d-x, xcode, release

do you know how to build mac build release version?
in this case i use cocos2dx framework.

in vs2013 we easyly choose the build version but in xcode i dont know.

the indication release build is all CCLOG would disappear in the game. but i have try toggle it in buildsetting pane. CCLOG still displayed in my console.

any suggestion? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

haha, solved in here http://applehelpwriter.com/2013/10/01/change-between-debug-and-release-build/. its too fast question :P

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using the cocos console to compile, add the tag

> -m release

which means **mode release**